# Manipulate plot with Eplilog where location of Point is given by a function outside of the Plot/Manipulate command

Tags: plotting, manipulate, piecewise

Consider a piecewise function such as

```
f = Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= x1}, {Sin[\[Pi] x], x1 < x <= x2}}]
```

I want to plot f using Manipulate and add a point on the plot at the location x = x1.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f /. {x1 -> xx1, x2 -> xx2}, {x, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{xx1, f /. x -> xx1 }]}
  ], {xx1, 1, 10}, {xx2, xx1 + 1, 50}]
```

This code fails because the Point command does not know what f is.  In this case it is trivial to just write in `Point[{xx1, xx1}]`, in my real problem f is defined after a number of other calculations and dependent on a number of variables both set separately and as part of the manipulate, and so cannot be defined explicitly here.

I tried wrapping the y coordinate in an `Evaluate` unsuccessfully.  The underlying `Plot` command does not work even without the `Manipulate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the definition of "Point". You need to replace not only x, but also x1 and x2:

```
f = Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= x1}, {Sin[\[Pi] x], x1 < x <= x2}}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[f /. {x1 -> xx1, x2 -> xx2}, {x, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point[{xx1, f /. { x -> xx1, x1 -> xx1, x2 -> xx2}}]}], {xx1, 1, 
  10}, {xx2, xx1 + 1, 50}]
```

[image]